# using one dictionary as the key for another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my question is say I have these words in a list.

```
[('John'), ('Jack'), ('Jeff')]
```

Then I have a dictionary with the following:

```
{'age': 1, 'height': 6, 'weight': 90}
```

Is it possible to combine these lists to create an output like this:

```
{'John': 'age': 1, 'height': 6, 'weight': 90}
```

Is it possible to have jack as the key and the others as the values like above? I don't want tuples around the values since I want to change them. Is it better to have it like this?

```
{('John'): 'age': 1, 'height': 6, 'weight': 90, ('Jack'),...(so on)}
```

Thanks,

Comment: No, your desired structure is not possible (you could make it, but it won't do what you want). You want a nested dictionary.

Comment: `{'John': {'age': 1, 'height': 6, 'weight': 90}, 'Jack': {...}, ...}`

Comment: @roganjosh Although I agree that this is the correct structure I think that a name is not a strong key. A name can have duplicates. I would probably do a `[{'name':John' ....` structure.

Comment: @AntonvBR That would depend. If the key is known to be unique then you're sacrificing a lot by doing that, but it's a fair point

Comment: @AntonvBR and that structure only gives you an assurance that data won't be overwritten in the case of duplicate names, but it gives no assurance on data retrieval since you'll just get your first match in an O(n) search

Comment: @roganjosh correct, but then again depends on the application. If the whole dataset is to be read anyway the time retrieval is irrelevant.

Comment: FYI. `('John')` is the same as `'John'`

Comment: "*I don't want tuples around the values*" - note what @HaiVu said, `('John')` is not a tuple it is a `str` (string).  `('John',)` is a tuple,  the comma makes it one, the parentheses are only needed for precedence and often are not required.  It is unclear why you would need a tuple there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think what most people would ask is: is your dictionary unique?

```
namelist = [('John'), ('Jack'), ('Jeff')]
dictionary = {'age': 1, 'height': 6, 'weight': 90}  # <--- is this the same for all names?
```

Anyway, you could store them all in an array with the name attribute. Something in the way of:

```
output = [{**{'name':i},**dictionary} for i in namelist]
```

---

This format is a well-known json-structure and is easily read by different libraries.
For instance, pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(output)
print(df)

#   age  height  name  weight
#0    1       6  John      90
#1    1       6  Jack      90
#2    1       6  Jeff      90
```